# Responsiveness, made in QT Designer, is not working. Python

Tags: python, qt, responsive-design, pyqt, qt-designer

I made an application design in QT Designer and saved it as a `.ui` file.
Next, converted `.ui` file into `.py` file with this command - `pyuic5 -o design.py responsive_design.ui`
After this, added this

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

at the end of a file to make it work.
But, unfortunately, when my Python file starts, application opens with a  static design, not responsive, as expected.
I see this - [image: not responsive design]

**Is it a QT bug or my mistake? Is it possible to resolve this problem?**

My full code is below -

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'responsive_design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 451))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Downloads/bg.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 0, 801, 451))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.label_3.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(1, 4)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 236), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 220));\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_11, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setToolTip("")
        self.label_10.setWhatsThis("")
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../microphone.png"))
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_10, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_9, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_8.setText("")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setStretch(0, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setStretch(1, 4)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setStretch(2, 5)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_14.setText("")
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_14)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_16.setText("")
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 236), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 220));\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.label_15.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_15, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setRowStretch(1, 3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setStretch(0, 4)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setStretch(2, 4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(0, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(1, 8)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(2, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(3, 6)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I'm listening when microphone is visible"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAID"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I Think You Said:"))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: use a box before placing elements then and install box or widget in box but don't install widget inside widget

Comment: @SimoNSavioR what do you mean? Can You post an answer, please?

Comment: A main layout must be set for the top level widget, while you created a further internal widget (verticalLayoutWidget) which is just "floating" in it, so it will never know when the window is resized and it will not adapt itself. I suggest you to create a new main window, start by dragging one of your widgets, right click on an empty area and select a proper layout from the "Lay out" menu. From there, restore the previous layout in the new window as you did before, and overwrite the previous file. Read more about using [layout managers in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first I installed the centrallayout, then I loaded all the elements to the layouts and I loaded these layouts to the centrallayout.

**check the differences and edit it yourself**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'responsive_design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QWidget



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()        
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Downloads/bg.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.centralLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.centralLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.label_3.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(1, 4)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 236), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 220));\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_11, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_10.setToolTip("")
        self.label_10.setWhatsThis("")
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../microphone.png"))
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_10, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_9, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_8.setText("")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setStretch(0, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setStretch(1, 4)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setStretch(2, 5)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_14.setText("")
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_14)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_16.setText("")
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 236), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 220));\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.label_15.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_15, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setRowStretch(1, 3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setStretch(0, 4)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setStretch(2, 4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(0, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(1, 8)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(2, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(3, 6)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I'm listening when microphone is visible"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAID"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I Think You Said:"))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "check the differences and edit it yourself": no, ***NO***. `pyuic` generated files should never, **ever** be manually edited, and encouraging this practice is a **terrible** suggestion. Didn't you notice the "Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing" warning?!?

Comment: I'm not discussing the code, but the fact that you *suggested* editing it. The required skills are pointless, as there are very few and very specific cases for which editing of pyuic files is *actually* required (and mostly due to minor bugs in pyuic); you can obviously do anything you want, but if you suggest a practice that is generally considered **bad**, and *also* the header of the file clearly discourages that, then it's just responsible to tell you about it, especially considering that we get at least 10 posts a week from people complaining about problems was caused by doing that.

Comment: My style may not suit you, but I will take what you say into account, sorry for my English :)

Comment: @musicamante, Sorry for this incident about pyuic generated files